# Cannot run Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-tools

i am getting the following error when i run `./android sdk` from the `android-sdk-linux/tools` folder. here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3550 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:328)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:302)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:118)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:101)
```

i tried reinstalling but no luck. if there is a way removing eclipse, android studio and all the packages i've installed together with them i would be glad to do this and make a clean install; as i also have an error with gradle.

Does anyone know any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by removing android studio and then installing it into another folder; just copy the content of your newly installed android studio to the old directory

Comment: What if I didn't do that and it was automatically updated in linux?